# Materialized views in oracle through DB link

Tags: oracle, privileges, materialized-views

I have materialized views created through db link in oracle database. I would like to refresh my MVs on demand every month.I have to do this through my ETL tool.Materialized views are in one schema and i'm trying to refresh it from a different schema.

I'm getting insufficient privilege error (ORA 06512) when running my ETL job to refresh the MVs. DBAs are not ready to provide ALTER ANY MATERIALIZED view privilege due to security reasons.

What are my options? Anyone faced something similar?

Comment: If the DBAs aren't will to give the privileges, just how do you expect this to work? Magic?

Comment: This is not clear. Why do you need ALTER ANY MATERIALIZED VIEW to run a refresh job? Perhaps you mean something different - do you need to ALTER the MV itself, perhaps to schedule the refresh frequency? At that point you may need the ALTER ANY MV privilege, but not when you run the actual refresh operation.

Comment: Yes, I need to schedule the refresh frequency. I'm doing it through my ETL job. While doing so, it throws insufficient privilege error (ORA 06512)